# Algorithm to align surface normal vectors

Tags: python, algorithm

I have some points on a surface (for which I have no mathematical formula).

I have an algorithm that gives me normal vectors for the surface (it's the same one that gives me the points, actually), but, unfortunately, the normal vectors are not "aligned".

I mean this in the sense that the algorithm returning a normal vector `n` arbitrarily returns either `n` or `-n`.  There is no way to tell, a priori, which I have received.  This is not necessarily a problem, but my vector field plot looks atrocious, since two points located right next to each other may have vectors pointing in opposite directions.  Thus, I would like to "align" my normal vectors, in the sense that I would like for most of them to reflect the same orientation of the object (i.e. to all point "outward" or to all point "inward")

I realize that there can be no perfect formula for this, but I am having a hard time developing an algorithm that does even a halfway good job.

My current algorithm takes the closest `k` points to the current one, determines how well the current normal vector aligns with the normals at those `k` points (via the dot product), average that and if it is "unaligned" with its neighbors, flip the vector.  I iterate this procedure a few times, to allow interaction between different points' neighborhoods.

Here's the code so far:

```py
import sklearn.neighbors
import numpy as np

def align_normals(data, normals, k=10, iterations=10):
    balltree = sklearn.neighbors.BallTree(data)
    pairwise_nearest_indices = balltree.query(data,k=k,sort_results=True,return_distance=False)
    for iteration in range(iterations):
        alignments = []
        for index in range(1,pairwise_nearest_indices.shape[1]):
            alignment = np.einsum("ij,ij->i",normals,normals[pairwise_nearest_indices[:,index]])
            alignments.append(alignment)
        alignment = np.average(alignments, axis=0)
        wrong_alignment = np.sign(alignment)
        normals = normals*wrong_alignment.reshape(-1,1)
    return normals
```

It has occurred to me that points at the "extremities" of the surface could easily be aligned to point outward, and then to work iteratively to align vectors near those.  However, all of my ideas so far seem to pretty much be a crap shoot.

Does anyone have any good ideas for aligning normal vectors?

Comment: You describe a vector field *plot*—is your concern merely with the graphics?

Comment: Normal orientation is a hard problem in general and there are quite a few approaches, ranging from simple to advanced. But if you have a surface, shouldn't you be able to get a consistent orientation from that? How do you calculate the normal?

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes.  I am actually going to be comparing the normal vectors at a later stage, but there will be an absolute value, and the negative will disappear.  However, it the meantime, I am trying to visualize the output of my algorithm, and it is much more difficult to see that the vectors are "correct-ish" when they point in the wrong direction.

Comment: I am using [subspace-constrained mean shift](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~aliyari/papers/PR1.pdf) to compute my surface.  This gives arbitrary points on the surface.  The hope is to then compute normal vectors via some out-of-the-box means given surface points.  Unfortunately, the algorithm that gives surface points does not provide an orientation for the surface.

Comment: @Scott: If their sign matters only for rendering, why not just draw the vector *and* its negative (or draw it offset by -0.5 of its own value) so as to get “toothpicks” embedded in the surface?

Comment: That is genius.